# Generic api calling using kotlin Reified in Ktor

Tags: android, ios, generics, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am new to KMM and trying to create a generic function for api calling using ktor with reified  and it seems to work fine with android but throws an error in iOS
This is my common api call return in Shared file.

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
suspend inline fun<reified T> post(url: String, requestBody: HashMap<String, Any>?) : Either<CustomException, T> {
    try {
        val response = httpClient.post<T> {
            url(BASE_URL.plus(url))
            contentType(ContentType.Any)
            if (requestBody != null) {
                body = requestBody
            }
            headers.remove("Content-Type")
            headers {
                append("Content-Type", "application/json")
                append("Accept", "application/json")
                append("Time-Zone", "+05:30")
                append("App-Version", "1.0.0(0)")
                append("Device-Type", "0")
            }
        }
        return Success(response)
    }  catch(e: Exception) {
        return Failure(e as CustomException)
    }
}
```

It works good in android if I call it like this :-

```
api.post<MyDataClassHere>(url = "url", getBody()).fold(
    {
        handleError(it)
    },
    {
        Log.d("Success", it.toString())
    }
)
```

But I am not able to get it run on iOS devices it shows me error like this :-

```
some : Error Domain=KotlinException Code=0 "unsupported call of reified inlined function `com.example.myapplication.shared.apicalls.SpaceXApi.post`" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported call of reified inlined function `com.example.myapplication.shared.apicalls.SpaceXApi.post`, KotlinException=kotlin.IllegalStateException: unsupported call of reified inlined function `com.example.myapplication.shared.apicalls.SpaceXApi.post`, KotlinExceptionOrigin=}
```

Any help in this is  appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so from the Slack conversation [here](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C0A974TJ9/p1608300739431800) it's clear that it's not possible to create this type of generic function as `swift` doesn't support `reified`. The only solution is we need to create different functions for every different api call we need.

For eg :- we can create a interface inside which we have all the api implementation and use it in the native platforms. Like this :-

```
interface ApiClient {
    suspend fun logIn(…): …
    suspend fun createBlogPost(…): …
    // etc
}
```

Now we can use this in our native platforms.