# I'm creating a serializable class exactly as the others but, Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to get a response from api and the Serialization it's not working, but it made the exactly the same with others data classes and they worked.

I am using ChangeFieldValueRequest data class as body to send with the request, as body, but i am receiving this message:

Failure(kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'ChangeFieldValueRequest' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.)

```
@Serializable
data class ChangeFieldValueRequest<T>(
    @SerialName("commercial_premise_id") val commercialPremiseId: Int,
    val field: String,
    val value: T
)
```

data class response

```
package com.quicktendr.mgmt.shared.domain

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class StatusResponse(
    val status: String,
    val error: String?
)
```

request:

```
suspend fun <T> updateLocalField(
        token: String, body: ChangeFieldValueRequest<T>
    ): StatusResponse {
        val request = handleError<StatusResponse> {
            httpClient.post("${baseUrl}api/management/updateLocalField") {
                this.body = body
                headers.append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)
                headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            }
        }
        when (request) {
            is ApiResult.Success -> {
                return request.value
            }
            is ApiResult.Error -> throw request.throwable
        }
    }


protected val httpClient: HttpClient = ServiceLocator.provideKtorHttpClient()
fun provideKtorHttpClient(): HttpClient {
        if(ktorHttpClient == null) {
            ktorHttpClient = HttpClient(generatePlatformHttpEngine()) {
                install(JsonFeature) {
                    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(Json {
                        encodeDefaults = true
                        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                        isLenient = true
                    })
                    accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
                }
                install(Logging) {
                    logger = Logger.DEFAULT
                    level = LogLevel.ALL
                }
            }
        }

        return ktorHttpClient!!
    }
```

gradle cofiguration :

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
...
}

   // kotlinx.serialization
    private const val ktxSerializationVersion = "1.0.1"

   // ktor
    private const val ktorVersion = "1.4.2"

    val ktxSerializationJson = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$ktxSerializationVersion"


 val ktorSerialization = "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion"
```

I have to send this on body:

```
{
    "commercial_premise_id": 95,
    "field":"delivery_paused",
        "value": true
}
```

And the response body will be this:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "error": null
}
```

Comment: can you please share what response you are getting from api ?

Comment: please share StatusResponse class. I'm guessing, since you have KotlinxSerializer installed, updateLocalField tries to deserialize the response into StatusResponse.

Comment: I got around the error, looks like was something with the generics involved. So, sadly, i edited the data classe to not use de generics, and created some other to supply the projects needs.

Comment: yes faced this similar issue once and turns out that you cannot use generics for api calling like we used to do in retrofit for android and alamofire in iOS in ktor for now. It does work in android but it won't work in iOS so it's not worth it I guess. you can have a look at my similar S.O Question/Answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358569/generic-api-calling-using-kotlin-reified-in-ktor

Answer (score 2):

You may miss the plugin `org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization`:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
    ...
}
```